# XNA Rotate Texture 2D

Tags: c#, xna

I'd like to rotate a Texture in XNA. I know I can rotate it when it is drawn, but I would like the Texture2D variable to be the rotated texture. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use RenderTarget, draw your texture rotated into the RenderTarget, take the texture and save it.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 5):

You should provide a new shader that manage texture coords rotation. As the HLSL code of the basiceffect is public, it should be pretty easy to add this behaviour.

[Basic Effect HLSL code](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/stock_effects)

Passing an angle parameter to the shader, the transform should be:

```
 newU = U*cos(alfa) - V*sin(alfa);
 newV = U*sin(alfa) + V*cos(alfa);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to pass a rotation matrix to your shader and multiply your texcoords by that before calling the texture sampler.

I'm not sure if XNA/DirectX has the same concept as OpenGL's texture matrix.