# Generating one Texture2D from multiple Texture2Ds

Tags: c#, xna

My problem is the I need to represent a length-changing floor using a Texture2D, which means a floor that the sides has the image of the sides, and in the middle it repeats the same 'middle' image, like so:
[image]

To achieve this, I get the 'left edge', the 'middle' and the 'right edge' textures, problem is I don't know how to merge them into one single texture2D,

It is important to do that at run-time because the floor length is changing (horizontally),
I read you can do that using SetData but I have no idea how...

It is very important for me that it will act as one texture and not multiple texture parts because I am using Farseer Physics Engine to move the floor and use it.

I am using C# and XNA with Visual Studio 2010, I am an almost-experienced C# programmer,

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466418/xna-rotate-texture-2d/7467165#7467165) may help you. Either you should use HLSL for repeating your floor or you should draw your floor on a RenderTarget and save it as single Texture. Enjoy.

Comment: What is HLSL, and can you give an example of 2nd solution, please?

Comment: Here's a little tutorial on [Render Target](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series3/Render_to_texture.php). Also, if you check that page a bit more, you'll find plenty of other tutorials, including HLSL.

Comment: There isn't really any need to write your own HLSL shader for this, as you aren't going to be doing anything which SpriteBatch can't handle.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a new [Texture2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.texture2d.aspx) to serve as your floor texture, specifying the appropriate width and height. Then, get the data of the three textures you want to merge, using the [GetData method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.getdata.aspx). Finally, use the [SetData method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.setdata.aspx) to set the data of the new texture as appropriate (check the link, you can specify the start index).

Warning: GetData and SetData methods are slow. If you need to create this texture only once per game (at the initialization for example), it's not a problem, though.

Comment: What if i need to create them lots of times?

Comment: Then the strategy suggested in the answer bellow is better.

Answer (score 1):

You are using farseer... but it does not prohibit you to use a tiling approach...

I don't know farseer, but I suppose that it provide a transform matrix...

do:

```
Vector2 pos = Vector2.Zero;
spriteBatch.Begin(...,....,...,..., Transform);

spriteBatch.Draw(LeftTexture, pos, null, Color.White);
pos.X += LeftTexture.Width;
for (int i=0; i<floor_repeats; i++)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(MidleTexture, pos , null, Color.White);
    pos.X += MiddleTexture.Width; 
}
spriteBatch.Draw(RightTexture, pos , null, Color.White);
```